# Диалог с предложением включить GPS

Tags: android, gps

Когда заходишь в Google Maps и у тебя выключен GPS, Андроид тебе предложит включить его диалогом с двумя кнопками. При нажатии на ОК - GPS включится.

Как сделать такой же диалог в своем приложении ?

И да, я правильно понимаю, что программно я никак не могу включить GPS без спрашивания пользователя ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Опросите систему включен ли GPS.

```
   public boolean isGeoDisabled() {
            LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean mIsGPSEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            boolean mIsNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            boolean mIsGeoDisabled = !mIsGPSEnabled && !mIsNetworkEnabled;
            return mIsGeoDisabled;
        }
```

если нет, покажите диалог с предложением включить, при согласии отправьте пользователя в настройки

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 4):

Программно включить без согласия пользователя вы не сможете.

Диалог можно реализовать например вот так:

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
public static boolean geolocationEnabled = false;

/**
 *  Проверяет включены ли соответствующие провайдеры локации
 */
private boolean checkLocationServiceEnabled() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        geolocationEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return buildAlertMessageNoLocationService(geolocationEnabled);
}

/**
 *  Показываем диалог и переводим пользователя к настройкам геолокации
 */
private boolean buildAlertMessageNoLocationService(boolean network_enabled) {
    String msg = !network_enabled ? getResources().getString(R.string.msg_switch_network) : null;

    if (msg != null) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setPositiveButton("Включить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Затем использовать как проверку в OnResume у активити: checkLocationServiceEnabled();

Comment: Спасибо за такой детальный ответ!